# Elisp: any way to stop edebug besides top-level?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm working on a function to break out of `edebug` while keeping
the arguments of current function bound.

```
(defun stop-edebug ()
  "Stop edebugging"
  (interactive)
  (if (not edebug-mode)
      (error "edebug isn't running!")
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-defun)
      (if (looking-at "(defun\\s-+\\_<[^ ]+\\_>\\s-+(")
          (progn
            (goto-char (match-end 0))
            (backward-char 1)
            (forward-sexp 1)
            (let ((sexps (mapcar
                          (lambda(x!) (cons x! (symbol-value x!)))
                          (preceding-sexp))))
              (edebug-mode -1)
              (mapc (lambda(x) (set (car x) (cdr x))) sexps)))))))
```

This way i can eval the function body at my own pace after `edebug` has bound
the function arguments for me.

The problem is that `(edebug-mode -1)` isn't really the way to exit
`edebug`. It leads `edebug` marker lingering in the buffer and maybe other
side-effects that I'm not aware of.
Normally, exiting is done with <kbd>q</kbd> that's bound to `top-level`.
But I don't how to call anything after `top-level` since
it's a jump straight to the main command loop.

So I'm asking either for a way to call something after `top-level`
or for a better way to exit `edebug` than `(edebug-mode -1)`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "stop edebug", please give some example.

Comment: I want to exit edebug minor mode.

Comment: I don't know what that means for you.

Comment: I want edebug key bindings to become inactive and I want the edebug visual cursor to disappear.

Comment: `q` does that.  `c` does it too, in a different way.  What should happen with the computation that's interrupted?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to call `q`, but also to do something afterwards. But since `q` is a call to `top-level`, all my code after that call is thrown away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run code after calling `top-level` you can schedule that code for later execution in a timer.  E.g.

```
...
(run-with-timer 0 nil 
                (lambda ()
                  (do the thing (here))))
(top-level))
```

Comment: Is there any guarantee on the order of execution? Is it for sure
that `(do the thing)` will be called after `top-level`?

Comment: Yes.  Timers are only run at "yield" points, e.g. when waiting for input.